# What would be the final hypothesis like? if our unknown target is a distribution rather than a function?

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, modeling, data-mining

[image]

The above picture is about building model, it seems a bit difficult to understand the meaning of "plus noise", and what would the final hypothesis look like? if the unknown target changes from function to distribution.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "target changes from function to distribution." Note that both are considered in the top left: $y$ is assumed to be randomly distributed around some unknown deterministic function. How would once change the target?

Answer (score 2):

The "plus noise" is meant to indicate the assumed mapping from $X$ to $y$. Namely, that there is some deterministic, unknown function $f$; $y$ is assumed to equal $f(X)$ plus random noise.

What the final hypothesis $g$ will "look like" depends on the hypothesis set. In general, it will be the member of the hypothesis set that minimizes the error measure. In a standard linear regression, for example, $g$ will be the linear function that minimizes squared error.